# SQL Server Express takes too long to wake up

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

I'm developing a web application using ASP.NET MVC 3 and Entity Framework Code First with SQL Server Express on the back end.

SQL Server Express [falls asleep by design](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2008/02/22/sql-express-behaviors-idle-time-resources-usage-auto-close-and-user-instances.aspx) to conserve system resources.  I'm fine with that behavior, but unfortunately the first time a page is hit after SQL Server Express has been idle for a long time, Entity Framework times out waiting for the DB to return from idle to active state.

Is there a global means to tell Entity Framework to wait longer for the database before throwing an Exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if DbContext API exposes any property to override default command timeout which is probably 30s for SQL Server provider. You can try to convert `DbContext` to `ObjectContext` and set the timeout there:

```
var ctx = ((IObjectContextAdapter) dbContext).ObjectContext;
ctx.CommandTimeout = 120;
```